# c - Proper range of return status / value

Tags: c, process, fork, return-value

Recently, when reading a book about linux programming, I got a message that:

> The status argument given to _exit() defines the termination status of the process, which is available to the parent of this process when it calls wait(). Although defined as an int, only the bottom 8 bits of status are actually made available to the parent. And only `0 ~ 127` is recommanded to use, because 128 ~ 255 could be confusing in shell due to some reason. Due to that `-1` will become `255` in 2's complement.

The above is about the exit status of a child process.

**My question is:**

- Why the parent process only get the 8 bits of the child process's exit status?
- What about return value of normal functions? Does it reasonable or befinit to use only `0 ~ 127` ? Because I do use `-1` as return value to indicate error sometimes, should I correct that in future.

---

**Update - status get by wait() / waitpid():**

I read more chps in the book (TLPI), and found there are more trick in the return status & wait()/waitpid() that worth mention, I should have read more chps before ask the question. Anyhow, I have add an answer by myself to describe about it, in case it might help someone in future.

Comment: This is a feature/limitation of the operating system (receiving the return value from `main`) and doesn't apply to internal functions in the program.

Comment: If these are the MSBs, then a value of 0..127 would yield `0` anyway. Sure you cited the text correctly? Looks strange to me, it should have been the least significant bits actually.

Comment: @Olaf 127 will still be 127 I think, because it's '0111,1111', it only take 8 bits.

Comment: "Because I do use -1 as return value to indicate error sometimes" - While this is not uncommon, it's not awfully clean either. API functions often return `0` for failure and another value for success. This allows idioms like `if ( ! myFunction() ) { bailOutWithErrorMsg(); }`.

Comment: @HannoBinder But it seems a lot system calls and glibc functions return 0 to indicate operation succeed, as well as the `main()`, right?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mixed them up :) `0` = OK, `-1` = error seems prevailant.

Comment: @HannoBinder: That seems to be from the [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exit.html) spec (which makes sense). Any value other than `0` (false) signals an error. The negative values (-128..-1) are used by the system, the positive >0 are for normally application-defined (with possibly further restrictions). That is actually a signed `char` in an `int` which will might be extended to `int` by the environment.

Comment: @EricWang: Do you actually understand what is meant by "MSBs"? If you only take the 8 MSBs of a 32 bit `int` (as demanded by POSIX) which contains 0..127, you will get `0`. As you cite it, it is definitively wrong, as I presumed.

Comment: @Olaf The book means `LSB`, not `MSB`, maybe my initial post didn't make that clear.

Comment: Well "din't make that clear ..." quite a euphemism. You actually stated the contrary. Please think of it next time.

Comment: You know, English is not my native language, so sometimes I make mistake on that. But sure nice tip, I will pay more attention to the words in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why the parent process only get the 8 bits of the child process's exit status?

Because POSIX [says so](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_Exit.html). And POSIX says so because that's how original Unix worked, and many operating system derived from it and modeled after it continue to work.

> What about return value of normal functions?

They are unrelated. Return whatever is reasonable. `-1` is as good as any other value, and is in fact a standard way to indicate an error in a huge lot of standard C and POSIX APIs.

Comment: That's what I hope it would be :)

Comment: POSIX [also states](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_Exit.html): "the full value shall be available from `waitid()` and in the `siginfo_t` passed to a signal handler for `SIGCHLD`."  So the full 32 bits **are** available on POSIX-compliant systems.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @n.m. is good.

But later on, I read more chps in the book (TLPI), and found there are more trick in the return status & wait()/waitpid() that worth mention, and that might be another important or root reason why child process can't use full bits of int when exit.

### Wait status

basicly:

- child process should exit with value within range of 1 byte, which is set as part of the status parameter of wait() / waitpid(),
- and only 2 LSB bytes of the status is used,

**byte usage of status:**

```
    event                   byte 1                  byte 0
    ============================================================
    * normal termination    exit status (0 ~ 255)   0
    * killed by signal      0                       termination signal (!=0)
    * stopped by signal     stop signal             0x7F
    * continued by signal               0xFFFF
    *
```

**dissect returned status:**

```
header 'sys/wait.h',  defines a set of macros that help to dissect a wait status,

macros:
* WIFEXITED(status)
    return true if child process exit normally,
* 
* WIFSIGNALED(status)
    return true if child process killed by signal,
* WTERMSIG(status)
    return signal number that terminate the process,
* WCOREDUMP(status)
    returns ture if child process produced a core dump file,
    tip:
        this macro is not in SUSv3, might absent on some system,
        thus better check whether it exists first, via:
            #ifdef WCOREDUMP
                // ...
            #endif
* 
* WIFSTOPPED(status)
    return true if child process stopped by signal,
* WSTOPSIG(status)
    return signal number that stopp the process,
* 
* WIFCONTINUED(status)
    return true if child process resumed by signal SIGCONT,
    tip:
        this macro is part of SUSv3, but some old linux or some unix might didn't impl it,
        thus better check whether it exists first, via:
            #ifdef WIFCONTINUED
                // ...
            #endif
*
```

---

### Sample code

**wait_status_test.c**

```
// dissect status returned by wait()/waitpid()
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define SLEEP_SEC 10 // sleep seconds of child process,

int wait_status_test() {
    pid_t cpid;

    // create child process,
    switch(cpid=fork()) {
        case -1: // failed
            printf("error while fork()\n");
            exit(errno);
        case 0: // success, child process goes here
            sleep(SLEEP_SEC);
            printf("child [%d], going to exit\n",(int)getpid());
            _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            break;
        default: // success, parent process goes here
            printf("parent [%d], child created [%d]\n", (int)getpid(), (int)cpid);
            break;
    }

    // wait child to terminate
    int status;
    int wait_flag = WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED;
    while(1) {
        if((cpid = waitpid(-1, &status, wait_flag)) == -1) {
            if(errno == ECHILD) {
                printf("no more child\n");
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            } else {
                printf("error while wait()\n");
                exit(-1);
            }
        }
        // disset status
        printf("parent [%d], child [%d] ", (int)getpid(), (int)cpid);
        if(WIFEXITED(status)) { // exit normal
            printf("exit normally with [%d]\n", status);
        } else if(WIFSIGNALED(status)) { // killed by signal
            char *dumpinfo = "unknow";
            #ifdef WCOREDUMP
                dumpinfo = WCOREDUMP(status)?"true":"false";
            #endif
            printf("killed by signal [%d], has dump [%s]\n", WTERMSIG(status), dumpinfo);
        } else if(WIFSTOPPED(status)) { // stopped by signal
            printf("stopped by signal [%d]\n", WSTOPSIG(status));
        #ifdef WIFCONTINUED
        } else if(WIFCONTINUED(status)) { // continued by signal
            printf("continued by signal SIGCONT\n", WSTOPSIG(status));
        #endif
        } else { // this should never happen
            printf("unknow event\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    wait_status_test();
    return 0;
}
```

**Compile:**

`gcc -Wall wait_status_test.c`

**Execute:**

- `./a.out` and wait it to terminate normally, child process id is printed after fork(),
- `./a.out`, then `kill -9 <child_process_id>` before it finish sleep,
- `./a.out`, then `kill -STOP <child_process_id>` before it finish sleep, then `kill -CONT <child_process_id>` to resume it,